# Display an image & hide it according to a variable

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I would like to display an image, in a specific area, according to a variable. For example, when the user click on an avatar, it shows an specific image. Once he clicks on other avatar, other image will be displayed.

I've tried to remove the previous image, and display new one, but it said "attempt to call removeself() with a nil value".

Define table in the start :

```
local item_bigsize = {}
```

So i tried this :

```
item[i] = display.newImageRect("items/"..items['pos'..i..'_name']..".png", 80 , 80)
item[i].x = holder_2[i].x+10
item[i].anchorX=0
item[i].y=holder_2[i].y
itemGroup:insert (item[i])
item[i].destination=i
item[i]:addEventListener( "touch", onSwitchPress )
```

and the function onSwitchPress() works like this :

```
function onSwitchPress( event )

i=event.target.destination

if (event.phase=="began") then

    title_item.text=""
    desc_item.text=""

    for n=1,3 do
        if n~=i then
            item_bigsize[n]:removeSelf( )
        end
        n=n+1
    end

elseif (event.phase == "ended") then

        item_bigsize[i] = display.newImageRect("items/"..items['pos'..i..'_name']..".png", 240 , 240)
        item_bigsize[i].x = 950
        item_bigsize[i].anchorX=0
        item_bigsize[i].y=display.contentCenterY-130
        group:insert (item_bigsize[i])


    title_item.text=items['pos'..i..'_title']
    desc_item.text=items['pos'..i..'_details']

end  


end
```

Comment: Where are you defining the "item_bigsize[]" table?   (Also, you forgot the index n inside that table)

Comment: In the starting file LUA just after the "required files"

Comment: You can use `item[i].isVisible=true` to show the image, and `false` to hide them.

Comment: @Albert : I already try it ! But I would like to remove the object and then create it when the user click on the object. I'll have more than 200 items, cannot create an image for each item (not necessary)

Comment: @Mehmet:Soga, you mean at the same time only one image would shown, right? In your code, I found your `item[X]` are all 80x80 and `item_bigsize[X]` are all 240x240, you can use `display.newSprite` and `item[i]:setFrame(X)` to show the image, see [Corona display.newSprite](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/newSprite.html)

Comment: @Mehmet :I wrote an example for you:[Example for Mehmet (In stackoverflow)](http://www.albert-feng.cn/blog/?post=8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
if n~=i then
  item_bigsize[n]:removeSelf( )
end
```

Try:

```
if(n~=i and item_bigsize[n].x~=nil)then --Check whether the object/properties exists
  item_bigsize[n]:removeSelf()
end
```

Keep Coding................ :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for n=1,3 do
    if n~=i then
        item_bigsize[n]:removeSelf( )
    end
    n=n+1
end
```

First of all why do you increment the value of n manually, the for loop will automatically increments n by 1.So you don't increment it.

So what happens here first time i = 1 and n = 1 the condition fails it will not remove.

second time n increments by and you are manually increments n by 1, so it will become three the condition satisfies because i will 2 be and will enters the loop, it will try to remove the image  item_bigsize[3]:removeSelf( )which is not present.

I think this could be the possible error, so remove the n = n+1.

```
for n=1,3 do
    if n~=i then
        item_bigsize[n]:removeSelf( )
    end
end
```

Comment: It still doesn't work ! I says attempt to index field '?' (a nil value). In fact i'm wondering if the position of my code to "remove" the image is correct.

Comment: By the way .. First, i is not automaticly equal 1 !" i" is a result of the "event.target.destination". So that means, if the user click on item #1, it doesn't remove the item_bigsize[1] but all others from 2 to 3 (for example).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have

```
item_bigsize[i]
```

Because "i" is not an integer which you want to iterate in "for".

Comment: Please give more details.. Why do you say i don't have "item_bigsize[i]" ?

Comment: so please explain what is the "i" value in "item[i] = display.newImageRect"

Comment: "i" value is coming for the "item[i].destination" and it's the ID of the item i need to display.

Comment: No way. You have to set value of "i" to get "item[i].destination". Otherwise it would be "item["nil"].destination".
The most common is to set "i" as an integer (1, 2, 3, 4, etc.) so if you type in "item[i]", you'll get i'th element from table "item". Take a look at this tutorial http://coronalabs.com/blog/2011/06/21/understanding-lua-tables-in-corona-sdk/

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i've choose to hide/show items as @albert said in previous comment (more simple). I also choose to work with DataBase SQLite3, instead of files because it's faster.

Here is the solution :

```
function ShowItems( event )


local count = 1
local sql = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE active='oui'"

n=1
number=0

    for x in db:urows "select count(*) from items" do 

            for row in db:nrows(sql) do

                            item[count] = display.newImageRect("items/"..row.src..".png", 80 , 80)
                            if n <= 7 then 
                                item[count].x = holder[n].x+10
                                item[count].y=holder[n].y
                            elseif n >= 8 and n<15 then
                                item[count].x = holder_2[n].x+10
                                item[count].y=holder_2[n].y
                            elseif n >=15 and n<=21 then
                                item[count].x = holder_3[n].x+10
                                item[count].y=holder_3[n].y
                            end
                            item[count].anchorX=0
                            itemGroup:insert (item[count])
                            item[count].destination=row.id
                            item[count]:addEventListener( "touch", onSwitchPress )
                            n=n+1  


                            item_bigsize[count] = display.newImageRect("items/"..row.src..".png", 240 , 240)
                            item_bigsize[count].x = 950
                            item_bigsize[count].anchorX=0
                            item_bigsize[count].y=display.contentCenterY-130
                            bigimages:insert (item_bigsize[count])
                            item_bigsize[count].isVisible=false                   


            count = count + 1
            end

        end  

end
```

and my function to show the "big" size images is :

```
function onSwitchPress( event )

i=event.target.destination

    if (event.phase=="began") then

        number = n-1
        number_equip = a-1

        title_item.text=""
        desc_item.text=""

        item_bigsize[i].isVisible=true

                            if n <= 7 then 
                                holder[i].alpha=1
                            elseif n >= 8 and n<15 then
                                holder_2[i].alpha=1
                            elseif n >=15 and n<=21 then
                                holder_3[i].alpha=1
                            end    

                      for increment=1,number do
                            if increment~=i then
                                  if item_bigsize[increment]~= nil then
                                      item_bigsize[increment].isVisible=false
                                        if n <= 7 then 
                                            holder[increment].alpha=0.5
                                        elseif n >= 8 and n<15 then
                                            holder_2[increment].alpha=0.5
                                        elseif n >=15 and n<=21 then
                                            holder_3[increment].alpha=0.5
                                        end

                                      --print( increment )
                                  end

                              end
                      end

    elseif (event.phase == "ended") then                                    

        result = "SELECT name,desc FROM items WHERE id ="..i..""

        for col1,col2 in db:urows( result ) do
            title_item.text=col1
            desc_item.text=col2
        end
    end  


end
```

This solution works very well for me !